# Join two queries with shared fields in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have two queries: QueryA and QueryB. Both produce similar results. QueryA: month, ID, countA and QueryB: month, ID, countB.

Each of these reports has unique values for the counts, but months and ID will be shared between the two. Example:

QueryA:

```
Month | ID | Count

 Jan | 1 | 57

 Feb | 1 | 63

 Jan | 2 | 44

 Feb | 2 | 11
```

QueryB:

```
Month | ID | Count 

 Jan | 1 | 22 

 Feb | 1 | 3 

 Jan | 2 | 99 

 Feb | 3 | 21
```

I need a final query that produces the following:
QueryC:

```
Month | ID | CountA | CountB

 Jan | 1 | 57 | 22

 Feb | 1 | 63 | 3

 Jan | 2 | 44 | 99

 Feb | 2 | 11 |

 Feb | 3 |      | 21
```

Please forgive any lacking formatting. I'm posting from my phone.

I need a final output that (1) provides a consolidated result for Month+ID that exists in both queries AND those that are in either of the queries... if in QueryA but not B, and if in QueryB but not A. All in one result (with no duplicates).

Comment: Create UNION query with 3 existing queries and then use it as a data source for consolidated query

Comment: @SergeyS. Please forgive but could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Variant 1, crosstab:

Create union query like this:

```
SELECT ID
    ,Mnth AS [Month]
    ,Cnt
    ,"CountA" AS hdr
FROM QueryA

UNION

SELECT ID
    ,Mnth AS [Month]
    ,Cnt
    ,"CountB"
FROM QueryB
```

Save it under name, for instance qryAll1.
Create crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(qryAll1.Cnt) AS SumOfCnt
SELECT qryAll1.ID
    ,qryAll1.Month
FROM qryAll1
GROUP BY qryAll1.ID
    ,qryAll1.Month
PIVOT qryAll1.hdr;
```

The same, using one query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(u.Cnt) AS SumOfCnt
SELECT u.ID
    ,u.Month
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,Mnth AS [Month]
        ,Cnt
        ,"CountA" AS hdr
    FROM QueryA
    UNION
    SELECT ID
        ,Mnth AS [Month]
        ,Cnt
        ,"CountB"
    FROM QueryB
    ) AS u
GROUP BY u.ID
    ,u.Month
PIVOT u.hdr;
```

### Variant 2, group by

Create union query

```
SELECT ID, Mnth as [Month], Cnt as CountA, 0 as CountB
FROM QueryA
UNION SELECT ID, Mnth as [Month], 0, Cnt
FROM QueryB;
```

Save it as qryAll2 and create query

```
SELECT qryAll2.ID
    ,qryAll2.Month
    ,Sum(qryAll2.CountA) AS SumOfCountA
    ,Sum(qryAll2.CountB) AS SumOfCountB
FROM qryAll2
GROUP BY qryAll2.ID
    ,qryAll2.Month
```

The same, using one query:

```
SELECT u.ID
    ,u.Month
    ,Sum(u.CountA) AS SumOfCountA
    ,Sum(u.CountB) AS SumOfCountB
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,Mnth AS [Month]
        ,Cnt AS CountA
        ,0 AS CountB
    FROM QueryA
    UNION
    SELECT ID
        ,Mnth AS [Month]
        ,0
        ,Cnt
    FROM QueryB
    ) AS u
GROUP BY u.ID
    ,u.Month
ORDER BY u.ID
    ,u.Month DESC;
```